# Bisection method error estimate

Tags: functions, roots, bisection

My task is to find how many iterations of bisection method should I do to find the root of a function with precision $10^{-5}$. The function is:
$f(x) =1-x-\sqrt{1-e^{-x}}$. If I do it by hand it might take too much time, I think there should be an algorithm for this but I can't find.

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method ("Analysis")

Comment: that looks like the answer for my question, thank you